# NodeJS child process stdout not returning completly

Tags: node.js, child-process

I'm running the following code using node and I always get only about 80% of what stdout is supposed to return when the file is past 12ko or so. If the file is 240ko it will still output 80% of it. If it's under 12 it will output completely.

When I open a cmd and run the command manually I always get the full output.

I tried exec, execFile, I tried increasing the max buffer or changing the encoding and it's not the issue. I tried to add options `{shell: true, detached: true}` but it vain, in fact, when I run it as detached it seems to be running completely fine as it does open an actual console but I'm not able to retrieve the stdout when the process is completed.

```js
const spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
const process = spawn(
    'C:\\Users\\jeanphilipped\\Desktop\\unrtf\\test\\unrtf.exe',
    ['--html' ,'C:\\Users\\jeanphilipped\\Desktop\\unrtf\\test\\tempaf45.rtf'],
);

let chunks = [];

process.stdout.on('data', function (msg) {
    chunks = [...chunks, ...msg];
});

process.on('exit', function (msg) {
   const buffer = Buffer.from(chunks);
   console.log(buffer.toString());
});
```

Any clues ? It seems to be Node since when I run it manually everything works fine.

Comment: have you tried using [for await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for-await...of) ```for await (chunk of process.stdout){}```

Comment: Why would you use `chunks = [...chunks, ...msg];` instead of `chunks.push(msg)`?

Comment: Coding recommendation (though may not affect your current problem).  Don't name your own variables `process` as that is a pre-defined global in node.js.

Comment: I'd suggest trying `process.on('close', ...)` instead of `process.on('exit', ...)` as the `close` event is directly tied to the stdout stream.  Also, the code examples in the child_process doc use the `close` event, not the `exit` event.

Comment: Thanks I also tried close and get the same result.

Answer (score -3):

according to nodejs documentation, all of the child_process commands are asynchronous . so when you try to access your chunk variable there is no guarantee that you command has been finished , maybe your command is still on process. so it is recommended you should wrap your entire child_process command in async/await function.

Comment: Isn't that what the listeners are there for ? When process.on('exit') triggers, you mean there is no guarantee that the process did infact finish ?

Comment: This makes no sense & cant call this an answer.

Comment: I just ran some tests with the listeners and with a hardcoded timeout and the stdout always cut at the same exact place.